# What is "Custom Program Error 0xa2" in anchor?

Tags: anchor, solana, anchor-solana

My Anchor program spits out an error that looks like: `custom program error 0xa2`. What does this mean? Where can I learn what this error means?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is `Error: 162: 8 byte discriminator did not match what was expected`.

That means anchor was expecting an account's data to start with a certain 8 bytes, but it didn't.

That could be because you passed in the wrong kind of account (so the first 8 bytes were totally wrong), or maybe because you're trying to use zero_copy and haven't actually written those bytes yet (need to use #[account(zero)] before you've run .load_init())

It also can happen if you're trying to reference an account from a program that wasn't originally written in Anchor, and now you're rewriting it in Anchor. You might need to write some custom serialization logic for this.